# How come enlightened people don't have any laziness?

Tags: enlightenment, self, science, five-hindrances, desire

I just heard that enlightened people have zero laziness. How is it possible? What is "laziness" ? What is the connection between laziness and ego/desire?

Edit: Also that monk said: "Laziness is caused by ignorance."

Comment: They have nothing further to do for this world, good householder.

Comment: @Samana , In buddhism, laziness means laziness to the meditaion/path , not every day life. Am I right ? , but how can I recognize laziness in day to day life ? What are the mental factors according to the Lord Buddha ?

Comment: Lazyness here means being busy with others than the path. Lack of samvega is the main reason for lazyness to act kusala, even path kusala: to work.Feeling secure in the decaying, one falls lacy.

Comment: @Samana, "Feeling secure in the decaying" is answered my question.  Thanks. I suggest you to post the comment as a answer. Thanks again :)

Comment: If some one knows the real danger of sansara, he will give up every thing to achive enlighment.

Comment: [The needed Goad, seeing Dukkha](https://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/an/an04/an04.113.than_en.html)

Comment: The fetter, btw, falls with the No-Returner attainment and loses any ground at Arahatship.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Speaking from the first hand experience, laziness comes from attachment, fear, or ignorance. No attachment, no fear, and no ignorance - translates to no laziness.

And how does attachment cause laziness? Someone is attached to what they think is a pleasant pastime, taking delight and enjoying that experience. For such person, anything apart from that experience is unpleasant, hence they will have inner resistance and avoidance: laziness.

And how does fear cause laziness? Someone is afraid of failure or is afraid of judgement or is afraid of difficulties, or is afraid of all three. For such person, doing anything that has a risk of the three looks dangerous, hence they will have inner resistance and avoidance: laziness.

And how does ignorance cause laziness? Someone is confused about what is important, confused about what's good and what's bad for oneself and others, confused what actions lead to what outcome. For such person there's no understanding: "this needs to be done". Having no understanding, they have no motivation. Having no motivation, they are lazy.

An enlightened one, having no attachment, taking no delight in pleasant experiences, having overcome the sign of "pleasant", having no fear, having no resistance to difficult experiences, having transcended the notion of "difficult" - does not have a basis for the arising of inner resistance and avoidance, therefore laziness can't arise. Having the perfect understanding of what's good and what's bad, knowing what is important, an enlightened one acts with wisdom and compassion.

Comment: How do you transcend difficult experiences? isn't that utopic at some level

Comment: The key is, you don't have to see them as "difficult" - that interpretation is up to you, and you can learn to see through it.

Comment: A remarkable explanation. Namo Buddhaya. May The Noble Triple gem bless you _/\_

Answer (score 1):

Once enlightened one does not have the [5 Hindrances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_hindrances) including [Thīna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C4%ABna)-[Middha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middha) which makes us lazy.

Answer (score 1):

I observed bodily feelings in myself with which I identified or at least liked. Especially in the sexual arena. They "made" me lazy. I had diffuculty to let go of these and really get going. I can see enlightened people to not have these problems. They are probably feeling much more alive from within and feeling good. There is probably no need for all the comfort stuff for them.

Hopefully that helped. Blessings!

Answer (score 1):

Laziness often is due to a lack of desire or motivation. This is due to ignorance, i.e., not knowing what is necessarily for oneself.

Enlightened people have zero laziness because their body & mind is without mental pollution & blockages thus their energy flows optimally & freely.